# Verilog Debouncing Module

Tags: verilog

I am implementing a shift register using four 4-1 muxes and four D flip flops and was given this module to use as a debouncer (which outputs to the clock of the shift register). I know how a debouncer works and why they are used but can someone please explain how this code works? Thanks.

```
module debounce(
    input D_in,
    input clk_in,
    input reset,
    output D_out
    );



reg q9, q8, q7, q6, q5, q4, q3, q2, q1, q0;

always @ ( posedge clk_in or posedge reset)

if (reset == 1'b1)

        {q9, q8, q7, q6, q5, q4, q3, q2, q1, q0} <= 10'b0;
    else begin
        q9 <= q8; q8 <= q7; q7 <= q6; q6 <= q5; q5 <= q4;
        q4 <= q3; q3 <= q2; q2 <= q1; q1 <= q0; q0 <= D_in;
    end

assign D_out = !q9 & q8 & q7 & q6 & q5 &
                q4 & q3 & q2 & q1 & q0;

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you have a 10-bit shift register (`reg [9:0] q`). On each positive edge of `clk_in` you put a `D_in` as a LSB of this register and shift left the rest of bits. That way you can check if `D_in` was high for 9 cycles (so you debounce it) and drive a `D_out` output:

```
assign D_out = !q9 & q8 & q7 & q6 & q5 & q4 & q3 & q2 & q1 & q0
```

What's more you have to check if the MSB of the shift register is `0`, so you'll get a `1` as an output only for one clock cycle.

Comment: why 8 cycles? and if any q value is zero for D_out won't it always output a zero ? @Qiu

Comment: @RayanAoun: 9 cycles, typo. Yes, if any q value is zero - output will be zero too. But that's how debouncer works -> you're looking for a situation, where signal was stable (and high) for 9 cycles in a row. But MSB (`q[9]`) need to be `0` or you can get "constant" `1`.